# When using redbean on xampp I noticed this error

Tags: macos, pdo, xampp, redbean

I am trying to test out redbeanphp and tried implementing it on xampp with my mac. 
However it seems like there is something wrong with my pdo. 
I've checked that a pdo driver for mysql is set up using phpinfo.
Can anyone please provide some insights or some directions on why this is happening.

Thanks in advance!

The code I am using is:

```
<?php
require('rb.php');
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hoodajax');
$book = R::dispense( 'book' );
$book->title = 'Boost development with RedBeanPHP';
$book->author = 'Charles Xavier'; 
$id = R::store($book);
$book = R::load('book', $id);
echo $book->title;
R::close();
?>
```

The error that is being displayed is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for
user ''@'localhost' to database 'hoodajax'' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ajax/rb.php:613
Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ajax/rb.php(613):
PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', NULL, NULL, Array) #1
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ajax/rb.php(790): RedBean_Driver_PDO->connect() #2
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ajax/rb.php(1755): RedBean_Driver_PDO->Escape('book') #3
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ajax/rb.php(2374): RedBean_Adapter_DBAdapter->escape('book') #4
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ajax/rb.php(2334): RedBean_QueryWriter_AQueryWriter->check('book')
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ajax/rb.php(4594):
RedBean_QueryWriter_AQueryWriter->safeTable('book', true) #6
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ajax/rb.php(4563):
RedBean_OODB->storeBean(Object(RedBean_OODBBean)) #7
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ajax/rb.php(6439): RedBean_OODB->store(Ob in
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ajax/rb.php on line 613
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory:

> Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'hoodajax'

You haven't specified a user name for the DB access.